# Does Objective-C use string pooling?

Tags: objective-c, string, memory, pool, string-literals

I know that [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801343/what-is-string-pool-in-java) and [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern) both use a string pool to save memory when dealing with string literals.

Does Objective-C use any such mechanism? If not, why not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, string literals like `@"Hello world"` are never released and they point to the same memory which means that pointer comparison is true.

```
NSString *str1 = @"Hello world";
NSString *str2 = @"Hello world";
if (str1 == str2) // Is true.
```

It also means that a weak string pointer won't change to nil (which happens for normal objects) since the string literal never gets released.

```
__weak NSString *str = @"Hello world";
if (str == nil) // This is false, the str still points to the string literal
```