# Why two strings allocated with NSString *str1 = [[NSString alloc]init]; have same address?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

```
NSString *str1 = [[NSString alloc]init];
NSString *str2 = [[NSString alloc]init];
NSLog(@"%p\n%p",str1,str2);

result

str1:0x7fff7b559d00
str2:0x7fff7b559d00
```

Why `str1` and `str2` have same memory address?

Comment: It looks like Objective-C uses string pooling (just like Java). 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556714/does-objective-c-use-string-pooling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSString` is immutable, so two empty strings are identical. Therefore, Cocoa can return the same object every time you create it.

The real question, however, how can this be done when `alloc` returns two different addresses for the two strings?

The answer is that `init` is allowed to substitute the value of `self` for anything it wishes, and return a completely different object. For example, `NSString`'s `init` can be implemented like this:

```
-(id)init {
    static NSString *empty = nil;
    if (!empty) {
        empty = [[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:"" length:0];
    }
    return empty;
}
```

**Note:** The real code in Cocoa will almost certainly be different; this is only an illustration to show how the same address could be returned for different allocations.