# Why does Java's String#replace() method work differently with characters and strings?

Tags: java, string

Why does the following expression evaluate as false

```
aStr.replace("H", "H") == "Hello"
```

while this alternate expression evaluates as true?

```
aStr.replace('H', 'H') == "Hello"
```

Comment: Use `.equals()` to compare `String`s.

Comment: Does `aStr` contain an 'H' character or not?

Comment: *Everyone* missed the root question, which was *not* a duplicate!  In this specific case, the implementation for `replace(char, char)` starts with `if (oldChar != newChar) { ... } return this;`

So your simple test returned the same instance... which is why the `==` succeeded.  As has already been mentioned, use `equals` to compare objects for equivalence, rather than the `==` which checks for *same* object instance.

Comment: I was in the middle of writing a lengthy answer to the real question, as Richard notes, but even then, if `aStr` does *not* contain an `H` character, then ever the first call to `String#replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)` should have also returned true. It does with Oracle's JDK. Study how `Matcher#replaceAll()` works to see why.

Comment: I re-opened this because I think a few folks have missed the actual question.

Answer (score 4):

Java caches `String` literal in String pool, so if there is no change in `String` it would take an immutable instance from pool and so that both refers to same instance in memory and thus `==` on reference returns `true`

So to compare String Object you should use `equals()` method / `compareTo()` method

---

**Also See**

- [What is String pool in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801343/what-is-string-pool-in-java)
- [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Answer (score 2):

String comparison should be done using `.equals()`

If the comparison is between String literals, then == comparison may work, because literals are cached in pool and refer to same variable.

`equals()` compares values, `==` compares reference.

Answer (score 2):

The `String` class's `replace(char, char)` method scans looking for a matching character. If it doesn't find one, it returns the host `String` instance as is. Naturally, comparing the returned reference to the original reference by way of the `==` operator returns true, as that's testing *reference equality*, and the two references are one and the same.

If, however, the original string contains an 'H' character—using your example here—then the returned string will *not* be the same as the original string (even though it will be the same character-by-character); it will be a freshly-allocated instance which would fail the comparison by reference equality (again, the `==` operator). Comparing the returned `String` with the original via `Object#equals()` would return true, as the two strings are *equivalent*, but they would be distinct instances that fail to match via reference equality.

By contrast, `String#replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)` treats the target string as a *regular expression*; it uses `Matcher#replaceAll()` internally to replace the matches in the target pattern with the supplied replacement sequence.

Now the question comes down to whether or not `Matcher#replaceAll()` will return the original string or a freshly-allocated copy even when the pattern *doesn't* match. By my reading of the code in the Oracle library, if the `Matcher` doesn't find the pattern to match, it returns `CharSequence#toString()` on the original `CharSequence`, which for a `String` objects just returns the `this` reference unmolested. That leaves me wondering whether you're reporting the true outcome here.

One glaring hole in the question as posed is the original content of the `String` referenced by `aStr`. You probably meant to show a declaration like

```
final String aStr = "Hello";
```

but you didn't. The outcome of both expressions should depend on whether `aStr` contains an 'H' character or not. Assuming it does, I expect both expressions to yield false, assuming that no [string *interning*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) is in play by either of the `String#replace()` overloads. We know that the string literals are interned, but the return values we see constructed in the Oracle library's implementation of both `String#replace()` methods are freshly allocated and not drawn from the intern pool.

Answer (score 0):

use String.equals () to compare strings.

```
        System.out.println((aStr.replace("H","H").equals("Hello")));
```

would return **true**.