# java equals and == confusion

Tags: java, equals, string-comparison, comparison-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is String pool in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801343/what-is-string-pool-in-java)

**1.** I know that **==** checks if two object are pointing to same memory location also the     default definition of **equals** uses **==** to do the checking, means both are same.

**2.**  **String** class overrides equals method to check if two string have same value.

Consider S1 = "test" and S2 = S1;

Now S1 and S2 are two different objects so as per point 1 **S1==S2** should be **false** and as per point 2 **S1.equals(S2)** should be **true** but when I ran this small program in eclipse both return true. Is there any special thing about string objects that S1 == S2 is also true.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801343/what-is-string-pool-in-java

Comment: And that is possibly the #1 Java question asked and already answered on this forum. ;)

Comment: "Now S1 and S2 are two different objects" - no, they're not. S2 and S1 are both references to the same string object.

Comment: when you initialize S2=S1 they both point to same memory location.

try

S1 = "test";
S2 = "test";

this will give you S1==S2 false

Comment: @PeterLawrey And everytime it is asked, it gets answered many times. What a waste of time... ;)

Comment: @Sandy, you will find similar behaviour with auto-boxed integers and boolean types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Consider S1 = "test" and S2 = S1; Now S1 and S2 are two different objects

Nope. This is where your argument fails.

You created *one* string object, and both your variables refer to the same string object. Assignment does *not* make a new copy of the string.

Answer (score 3):

When you write

```
s1 = s2;
```

`s1` and `s2` are references to the same object, so `s1 == s2` will always return true.

More confusing - if you write:

```
s1 = "test";
s2 = "test";
s3 = new String("test");
```

you will find out that `s1 == s2` is true but `s1 == s3` is false. This is explained in more details [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Answer (score 2):

Wiritng S1 = S2 results in them pointing towards the same object

Writing

```
String S1 = "test"
String S2 = "test"
```

Will yield the same results as you have now.
This is due to compiler optimisation, the compiler notices the string class which is immutable, therefore he will optimise the code to both use the same instance. You can force him to make new strings by instaniating them with a constructor

```
String s1  = new String("test");
String s2  = new String("test");
System.out.println(s1 == s2) // false
System.out.println(s1.equals(s2)) //true
```

Answer (score 1):

when you initialize

```
S2=S1
```

they both point to same memory location.

try

```
S1 = "test"; 
S2 = "test";
```

this will give you

```
 S1==S2 //false
```