# Java String : How many Objects are created

Tags: java

I am asking a duplicate Question, but i went through all the questions like this on Stack Overflow, but i am not able to Understand.

My Code is:

```
String s1 = "a";
String s2 = "b";
String s3 = s1 + s2;
```

1 . How many Objects are created?
2 . How can we say that objects are already present in String Table ?

-- **Really Sorry for duplicity, but i must know the correct answer**.

Comment: Any link or answers will be appriciated.

Comment: What do you mean by String Table? [String Pool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801343/what-is-string-pool-in-java)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801343/what-is-string-pool-in-java and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881922/questions-about-javas-string-pool

Comment: If you want to downvote please do it, but give me an answer also?I know its a question asked thousand times, but i am not getting the explanation, i am not as intelligent as you guys. Do give answers, please.

Answer (score 1):

Three Object will be created here in `String` pool.

```
String s1 = "a"; // 1st Object
String s2 = "b"; // 2nd Object
String s3 = s1 + s2; // "ab" 3rd Object.
```

if string is available in pool then it automatically pointing that object instead of creating new Object.

```
String str1 = "abc";
String str2 = "abc";
```

There will be one "abc" in `string` and both str1 and str2 pointing to same "abc". In case any modification happens like `str2 +="d";` then it will create a new Object in pool `"abcd"` because once Object is created we can not change its value.

Note : `String` is immutable.

Answer (score 0):

3 objects are created here.

The first two objects are obvious:

```
String s1 = "a"; // First
String s2 = "b"; // Second
```

The third object is a new object

```
String s3 = "a" + "b"; // Third
```

The only relation it has to `s1` and `s2` is that it contains the same letters as them, but it is a completely independent object. It's basically built like this:

```
String s3 = new String(s1.toString() + s2.toString());
```

Even if 2 strings contain the same character sequence they are not the same string.

```
String s4 = "foo";
String s5 = "foo";
```

**EDIT**

```
s4 == s5;       // Evaluates to true
s4.equals(s5);  // Evaluates to true
```

Both of the above will evaluate to true because of string pooling but are still separate objects. They use the flyweight design pattern in order to save memory.

On the other hand:

```
String s6 = new String("foo");
String s7 = new String("foo");

s6 == s7;      // Evaluates to false
s6.equals(s7); // Evaluates to true
```

Comment: Actually `s4 == s5` will evaluate to `true` (thanks to String Pool it will be exactly same object). If you would like to make them different objects you would need to use one of String constructors like `String s4 = new String("foo")`

Comment: That's right thanks. I edited above.

Answer (score 0):

Three object will be created in the above example.
As String is immutable, every time you try to change the value o string a new object will be created.

```
String s1 = "a" // 1st object
String s2 = "b" // 2nd object
String s3 = s1+ s2 // in this case a new onject with value "ab" will be created
```