# string trim function is not working

Tags: java, string, trim

I learned `string.trim()` removes leading and trailing spaces. But in my case its not working i am trying below code but output is with leading and trailing space. But my expectation is text without leading and trailing space. Here is my code.

```
String s = " Hello Rais ";
s += " Welcome to my World ";
s.trim( );
System.out.println(s);
```

Please help me

Comment: [The API in this case is very helpful.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim())  You *do* have to reassign it to the String you want - Strings are immutable.

Comment: @Real - repeat after me.  "Java Strings are immutable".  :-)

Comment: @StephenC My code is working i was making a silli mistake. I have to assingned the return of trim function to the variable. I dont understand What are you trying to say in above comment.

Comment: What did you see vs. What did you expect to see?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to re-assign the result of `trim` back to `s`:

```
s = s.trim();
```

Remember, ***Strings in Java are immutable***, so **almost** all the String class methods will create and return a new string, rather than modifying the string in place.

---

Although this is off-topic, but (as I said there `almost`), it's worth knowing that, exception to this rule is when creating a `substring` of same length, or any time a method returns the string with the same value, which will be optimized and will not create a new string, but simply return `this`.

```
String s = "Rohit";
String s2 = s.substring(0, s.length());

System.out.println(s == s2); // will print true
```

Comment: +1 `System.out.println(s == s2);` will be true because s and s2 has same value so for optimization they will hold same place in string pool managed by jvm. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801343/what-is-string-pool-in-java

Comment: @Rohit - thanks it was my mistake i forgot to re assign

Comment: @TapasBose. Yeah right. Should have mentioned that point. Thanks :)

Comment: You shoud use System.out.println(s.eqauals(s2)) to check the equality.

Comment: @MayurB. Is that for me? Thanks but I know that. The code is just an illustration of exception where `==` returns `true`.

Answer (score 6):

In Java Strings are `immutable`. So `s.trim()` does not modify the original string but returns a new string.

```
String trimmed  = s.trim();
```

Answer (score 4):

just add `s=s.trim( );` because trim returns a **new string**.

Answer (score 3):

Well..string is immutable object. so whenever you do trim(), it creates a brand new String object, which need to have a reference to access it. So do assign a reference to this trimmed String object as follows.

```
s = s.trim();
```

or

```
trimmedS = s.trim();
```

Answer (score 3):

Understand that `String` in Java is immutable. Which means any operation on the `String` class does not change the internal string itself, but returns a new `String` object.

So you really need to do

`s = s.trim()`

which assigns the reference `s` to a new `String` object that has its trailing and leading spaces removed.

Answer (score 2):

`trim` function returns a copy of the original string by trimming the white spaces so you need to store the newly returned string like `s = s.trim()`

From the [javadocs of String#trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29)

```
trim

public String trim()
Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.
```