# Java String manipulation query using trim() and length()

Tags: java, string, trim

```
public class X {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s1=" abc xyz ";
        System.out.println(s1.length());
        s1.trim();
        System.out.println(s1.length());
        System.out.println(s1.trim().length());
    }
}
```

O/p:

```
9
9
7
```

Kindly explain to me why `s1.trim().length()` is 7 and not 9 as `s1` will still be pointing to the old string ie " abc xyz " ?

Comment: Strings are __immutable__.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919019/string-trim-function-is-not-working

Comment: @devnull just checked your profile@SO, It is so funny that, in "about me" section we have "tried" to find the similar thing. :-D

Comment: @Duncan You feel like a superhero? :-)

Comment: @Duncan Yes, you weren't aware?  You can use the hammer for closing a question containing a tag for which you have a gold badge.

Comment: @Duncan Also see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-superpowers  -- I've made use of the _hammer_ in a certain tag and it's very satisfying.

Comment: @Kent Yes, I'm _actually_ trying to find it.

Comment: @Kent Who's that kid with the vim shirt on?

Comment: @devnull not my son... :-D it is a photo on internet named **vim rocks**.

Comment: @Kent I always thought that it would be your son.  Finally asked about it and the doubt was cleared.  (Otherwise I'd have been tempted to say that it's unfair.  Give your son a chance to familiarize with _emacs_ too :-D

Comment: @devnull I would buy one for my son when he can wear, and I would for sure replace the logo then...  perhaps this summer or next. but no doubt, it must be vim shirt! :-) vim rocks!!

Answer (score 2):

```
s1=s1.trim(); // trim() returns the "trimmed" String. You have to set it back to the reference
```

Answer (score 1):

`s1.trim();` does return trimmed string so capture in some variable to modify it.

in your case it left `s1` as it is. so when you call `s1.length()` it provide original `s1`s length.

if you want to modify it try `s1=s1.trim();`

Answer (score 0):

Trim returns the new string rather than modifying it.