# trim() does not working

Tags: java, string

```
String m1 = nextLine[6]; //"9602612325 "
m1 = m1.trim();                                  
if(m1 != null && !m1.isEmpty()){
      mob1 = Double.parseDouble(m1);
}else{
      mob1 = 0; 
}
```

I am trying to remove the space in

> String m1 = "9602612325 ";

I've gone through the following links [string trim function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919019/string-trim-function-is-not-working) and [string pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801343/what-is-string-pool-in-java) but still couldn't find the answer. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: Not really, since we have no idea *how* it's not working for you. You'll need to elaborate.

Comment: One problem: you're calling `m1.trim()` *before* you've done your null test.

Comment: actually the number "9602612325 " is ending with space, how can i remove that?

Comment: 1st line seems annoying !!

Comment: Sometimes, there is a case, it may not be the `space`, rather could be `non-breakable space`, `n space`, `m space` etc., In wich the `trim()` will not work for some characters. Make sure the last character is space.

Comment: @VinodKumar  m1.string.replace("\u00A0",""); this line solved my problem. thanks all.

Comment: Very well, that is a `non-breakable space`. Let me add an answer for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, there is a case, it may not be the space, rather could be `non-breakable space`, `n space`, `m space` etc.,
In wich the `trim()` will not work for some characters.
Make sure the last character is space.

If the last character is not space, then you could write your own logic to do that.

```
String text = " my text ";
char[] trimChars = {'\u00A0', ' '};//Add anything else you like to trim.
bool isSpaceBefore = false, isSpaceAfter = false;
do {
    isSpaceAfter = false;
    isSpaceBefore = false;
    for(int c=0; c<trimChars.length; c++) {
        isSpaceBefore = text.indexOf(trimChars[c]) == 0;
        isSpaceAfter = text.lastIndexOf(trimChars[c]) == text.length-1;
    }
    if(isSpaceAfter) text = text.substring(0, text.length-1);
    if(isSpaceBefore) text = text.substring(1);
}
while(isSpaceBefore || isSpaceAfter);
```

as a simplified version, you could use a find and replace also. But note that the replace will replace any characters that match even if they are in the middle of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
String m1 = "9602612325 ";
if(! Strings.isNullOrEmpty(m1)){ // Google Guava's utility class --> Strings
     m1 = m1.trim();
     try{
      mob1 = Double.parseDouble(m1);
      }
     catch(NumberFormatException e){
       mob1=0;
      }
}
else{
    mob1=0;
}
```

Note : You can also check manually for null and empty like this

```
if("".equals(m1)){    // here you need not to check for null seperately
 //do Whatever you need to do 
}
```

Comment: I liked the **"".equals(m1)**  <-- never thought about it :)

Comment: @nafas it is example of [yoda conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions).