# Java object initialization - When is it necessary?

Tags: java, initialization

I'm curious about java initialization:
When is it necessary to initialize objects like this:

```java
String init = new String("");
```

and which objects - like Strings - don't have to be initialized like above?

```java
String init = "";
```

Comment: Your are initialising `init` in both cases.

Comment: Strings don't have to be initialized?

Comment: Then my question is which objects need the "new Object()" initialization?

Comment: you should definitively read Effective java 2nd edition Item 5: Avoid creating unnecessary objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment on your question:

> Then my question is which objects need the "new Object()" initialization?

You're asking about *construction*, not initialization.

All objects need to be constructed by someone. The strings created by string literals are constructed by the JVM. You basically never want to use `new String("text content here")`.

There are several other objects constructed by the JVM, such as the `Class` object for each class you load. But other than `String`, for objects you want to interact with, you usually either have to explicitly construct them (via `new`) or receive them from a method that constructs them. `String` is a bit special because it's the only object type in Java (I *think*) with a literal notation. (All of the other literals, like `42` or `false`, are primitives.)

Answer (score 2):

Basically there's a subtle difference between the 2 ways of initialization you mentioned:
When you use:

```
String str = new String("");
```

a new `String` object is created on the heap and `str` points to it.

But in the latter case:

```
String str = "";
```

If there is already a string with this value ("") on the [string pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801343/what-is-string-pool-in-java), then the reference is initialized to point to it and no new object is created. If it is not found in the string pool, then a new string is created in the string pool and `str` is initialized to point to it.

Comment: So both ways have the same result if a string isn't found in the string pool?

Comment: no, because a string allocated using the first construct(with `new`) will not be found later in the string pool, while using the second notation the object will be allocated in the string pool and subsequent uses of this string will return the same reference.

Answer (score 1):

For strings, you almost always want to use the second form. It does less work for what -- in most circumstances -- is the same result.

The same advice goes for numeric classes, such as `Integer`, `Double`, etc.

In all other cases you don't normally have the choice, and have to use the first form.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, all objects must be initialized. The second case `init = ""` is also an initialization, except that the compiler lets you avoid the explicit call: object creation is still there. Starting with Java 5, the compiler also "knows" about wrappers for Java primitives, letting you use primitive constants in expressions that require a wrapper class (this is called [*autoboxing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)).

All local variables must be initialized explicitly, while member fields can be initialized implicitly to `null` or the default value of the primitive.

Answer (score 1):

All Objects have to be initialized with `new` but some, like these for example:

```
 String myString= "";
 Integer myInteger= 2;
 Float myFloat= 2f;
 Double myDouble= 2d;
 Byte myByte = 2;
```

and every kind of array, which can be initialized like `T[] array = {//list some Ts};

Comment: In what way is it untrue? That this is not a proper initialization (without using `new`) or that there are other objects that can be initialized without `new`?

Answer (score 1):

```
String s1 = "1";
String s2 = new String("2");
int i1 = 1;
int i2 = new Integer(2);
long l1 = 1l;
long l2 = new Long(2l);
float f1 = 1f;
float f2 = new Float(2f);
double d1 = 1d;
double d2 = new Double(2d);
char c1 = '1';
char c2 = new Character('2');
byte b1 = 1;
byte b2 = new Byte((byte) 2);
int[] a1 = {1};
int[] a2 = new int[] {2};
```

Comment: in cases like this `int i2 = new Integer(2);` you are actually casting from `Integer` to `int` while `int` is not an `Object` but a `primitive`

Answer (score 1):

Most classes require explicit construction (the new), however a few classes does not, these are the autoboxing classes (String, Integer, Double, and a few more, as well as arrays of these (using the comma seperated list initiliazation)) and these are the only ones!

What happens at the compiler level is really just that the compiler translates the implicit construction to an explicit one (e.g. One using new)

Answer (score 1):

All objects need to be initialized before they can be used. You can try declaring:

```
int myPrimitiveInt;
Integer myObjectInt;
```

But myPrimitiveInt cannot be used until you give it a value, and myObjectInt is implicitly initialized as null. For either of these to be used (except to get a null from the object), they need to be given a value, whether you use a constructor or not.

```
myPrimitiveInt = 5;
myObjectInt = new Integer(5);
myObjectInt = 5;
```

Comment: If those variables are instance fields, then they are implicitly initialized to `null`, and you can use them without assigning anything to them.