# String as an object in pool or as a reference?

Tags: java, string

I'm a little confused on what does string pool actually contain.

When we say `String s = "abc"`, does this mean that during compile time, the string object is put in the string pool or is it the reference that is put?

Comment: Go thro Link

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801343/what-is-string-pool-in-java][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801343/what-is-string-pool-in-java

Answer (score 1):

The statement `String s = "abc"` causes the `abc` to be created in String constant pool if it is not already present. If it is present, then a reference will be returned . You can find a good tutorial about string constant pool here.

http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/19/the-string-constant-pool/

Answer (score 1):

Each time you create a String that way, the JVM checks whether this Object is in the String constant pool. If so, a *reference* to the "pooled" instance will be returned. If it doesn't, a new instance initialized and put in the pool:

```
          ----------- String s = "Hello";
          |
          ٧
+-------------------+   
|      "Hello"      |
+-------------------+
        pool
```

Answer (score 1):

String pool is just a cache for string literal.Whenever we assign string literal to string reference ,literal will be searched in string pool and it will be assigned to reference variable.
In `String s="abc"` JVM  will search literal `"abc"` in string pool and will be assign reference of it to reference variable `s`.

```
                  ____________
          refers |           | 
String s ------->|   abc     |<---- String Pool 
                 |___________|
```

Answer (score 0):

The pool you are talking about is in the heap and all the references that exist are present on stack(not heap). When you create a string `String s = "abc";` String literal "abc" is placed in the String pool and all further references will point to this literal except the case in which you create a String object using new(separate memory space is allocated on the heap in this case).

Answer (score 0):

The string pool refers to a place in memory where Strings are defined. The string pool has references to constants to be reused. The string pool is what allows this to happen:

```
String a = "a" + "b";
String b = "ab";
if(a == b) {
System.out.println("this will print");
}
```

a==b will evaluate to true, because the compiler sees both String a and String b as equal to "ab" so this string is stored in the String pool and both String a and String b point to this one reference.

Answer (score 0):

"abc" is defined at compile time here and hence would be automatically interned. This string **object** will hence go to string intern pool. If one already exists there, its reference would be returned.The string intern pool is a part of main java heap since Java 7(and we know heaps are to contain objects).