# Creating an object from a class

Tags: java

For example

```
Dictionary webster = new Dictionary();
```

what does each dictionary mean technically? I understand that I'm creating a object that has its methods and variables. But what causes this?

Furthermore I am learning about Data structures.. Same exact question really but can the left and right side be different? Ex

```
ArrayList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
```

I know

```
ArrayList<String list = new ArrayList<String>(); works
```

but like I said I'm confused on what each side brings when my object is created..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686647/whats-the-best-way-to-define-the-words-class-and-object-to-someone-who-hasn ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211215/what-happens-when-you-create-a-new-object ... long story short: did you try **any** prior research?

Comment: Learn the basic of Object Oriented Programming and its features like Inheritance and Polymorphism.

Comment: @ghostcat those had zero help for me. I mean the left side Dictionary, what does that mean, compared to the right side.

Comment: You define a some entity is of a certain type. Like saying "Child baby = my newborn niece". But again: this is not programming school where you get **taught** such super basic things.

Comment: Can someone else explain. I know how to create objects from classes. I just don't know why we call Dictionary twice.... School didn't teach this

Comment: @twokdavey Hi, seems you are stuck at very basic level and the topic being very broad, i suggest you to go through some java basics material. You can refer Head First Java, First 5 chapters will align you.

Comment: @vv88 thank you for your kind guidance, I figured it was called decoupling after I talked to a old friend about it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> what does each dictionary mean technically?

The first `Dictionary` indicates that the type of the variable is `Dictionary`. Since you're creating a new dictionary, you call the `Dictionary` class' constructor i.e. `Dictionary()`. You can think of the `new` keyword as a word that you need to write in order to call any constructor.

That said, these are two valid statements (although they don't do anything practical):

```
Dictionary dict; // declares a variable of type Dictionary but doesn't give it a value
new Dictionary(); // creates a new dictionary but doesn't put it into some variable
```

> Same exact question really but can the left and right side be different?

This is called *polymorphism*. As I said, the first `Dictionary` represents the type of the variable, so `AbstractList<String>` here:

```
AbstractList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
```

represents the type of the variable `list` as well.

However, a variable of type `AbstractList` not only can store `AbstractList` objects. It can also store objects that are compatible with `AbstractList`. In this case, it is storing a `LinkedList<String>`.

You might ask why `LinkedList` compatible with `AbstractList`. Because the former inherits from the latter!

To sum up,

```
AbstractList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
```

The left side says:

> I have a variable that can only store `AbstractList<String>` objects and objects that are compatible with it.

The right side says:

> I'm creating a new `LinkedList<String>` by calling its constructor.