# How to use input obtained from a string in Java?

Tags: java, string, user-input

I have the following piece of code, and I'm trying to use the input entered by the user in if/else statements later on:

```
String userGuess = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("The first card is " 
    + firstCard + ". Will the next card be higher, lower or equal?");
```

How can I use the word they input, i.e. "higher", "lower" or "equal" outside of the if/else statement that this code is in? The code I need their answer for is:

```
if (userGuess == "higher" && nextCard > firstCard)
{
    String userGuess = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Correct! The current card is a " 
               + nextCard + ". Will the next card be higher, lower or equal?");
    correctGuesses++;
}
```

EDIT: Thank you for your help, I figured it out!

Comment: You should use `equals` instead of `==` to compare strings, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java?rq=1

Comment: `.equalsIgnoreCase` is how we compare `Strings`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
if (userGuess.equalsIgnoreCase("higher") && nextCard > firstCard)
{
    String userGuess = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Correct! The current card is a " 
           + nextCard + ". Will the next card be higher, lower or equal?");
    correctGuesses++;
}

else if (userGuess.equalsIgnoreCase("higher") && nextCard == firstCard)
{
    String userGuess = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Correct! The current card is a " 
               + nextCard + ". Will the next card be higher, lower or equal?");
    correctGuesses++;
}

else if (userGuess.equalsIgnoreCase("lower") && nextCard < firstCard)
{
    String userGuess = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Correct! The current card is a " 
               + nextCard + ". Will the next card be higher, lower or equal?");
    correctGuesses++;
}
```

`String` is not a primitive type. You cannot use `==` instead use:

```
if (userGuess.equalsIgnoreCase("higher") && nextCard > firstCard)
{
```

Take a look at Oracle's [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) on Strings. This should give you further help.
Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the variable `userGuess` outside of the if-statement, and just assign it inside, then you will be able to use it outside of the if-statement.

Also, as was stated elsewhere, you should be comparing string with equals(), not ==.

Comment: Wrong. That's not their problem. Their `if ()` statement is not testing correctly. They have already done that.

Comment: That is true and will cause problems, but the actual question they were asking was about the scope of the variable was it not?

Comment: @Galen Nare I see what you mean now. Reading over it again, he has 2 variables named userGuess.

Answer (score 0):

There are two decent ways:

1. Change the name of the variable (so it doesn't conflict with the existing userGuess variable) and declare it outside of the if statement.

   ```
   String nextGuess = "";
   if (userGuess.equals("higher") && nextCard > firstCard) {
       nextGuess = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Correct! The current card is a " + nextCard + ". Will the next card be higher, lower or equal?");
       correctGuesses++;
   }
   ```
2. Just use the same userGuess variable every time you have the user enter something.

   ```
   if (userGuess.equals("higher") && nextCard > firstCard) {
       userGuess = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Correct! The current card is a " + nextCard + ". Will the next card be higher, lower or equal?");
       correctGuesses++;
   }
   ```

Comment: Everyone hasn't noticed that `String`s can't be compared with `==`.

Comment: Strings can be compared with ==. You just might not get the result you expect. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801343/what-is-string-pool-in-java

Comment: Sure, but in my experience it always returns `false`.