# Add characters to an empty String after it is initialized

Tags: java, string, resize

Just curious as to how I would add a letter or character to a pre-existing `string`.

Here is what I'm trying to do,

I'm taking a key and its cipher text and subtracting their values (stored in arraylist) to find the plaintext value (I get an int, and then use that to find the String value in the arraylist) and then continue to do that for each letter in the two strings(Cipher and Key).

Is this possible, or would I have to use a `substring` or something along those lines.

Any suggestions on how to do this, or the answer to my initial question is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: You can't change an actual `String` object; but you can take a variable that references a `String` object, and make it reference a different one.  Is that what you require?

Comment: I'm going to edit the question quickly and add more detail to it. One moment :P

Comment: I am still wondering how you are using `ArrayList` to store key value. Anyway you can use `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I am not getting this part `I get an int, and then use that to find the String value in the arraylist` ?

Comment: @Nik well,first off, the "Key" is any bunch of letters, Ex: "ADIFG". What I did was add an array of letters(A-Z) to the ArrayList, then simply using their index in the ArrayList, I can an int, to use to subtract from the corresponding cipher keys value(of the current character we are examining) and then using THAT number, again,to get the letter stored at that index in the ArrayList. Hope that makes sense :P

Comment: @BhavikShah Read my above comment, its my best explanation for it quickly.

Comment: So you have 2 keys("ADIFG" and an cipher key), you map the key("ADIFG") to the value in arraylist, and then use cipher key to map same value in the arraylist again...if the 2 values are equal the test pass other wise fail...right?

Comment: @SullyBrooks I guess I got it. I took it as conventional `key-value` thing. My bad.

Comment: @Nik Yes, I would have used a Map or TreeMap if that were the case, but I figured this would work equally as well, and a bit less work.

Comment: @BhavikShah  Okay, so here is what the program actually DOES. I take in a text file that has a list of Values. The order of the values of the list go like so CIPHERTEXT (New Line) KEY.  Then what the program does is, if they key is shorter than the ciphertext, then adjust that to fit the length(where I actually used a StringBuilder for that method). Then, once that is adjusted, a new method takes those values and tries to decipher them. It does this by subtracting the value of EACH character of the key (A=1,B=2,C=3...Z=26) from its corresponding character in the Cipher text. Will continue..

Comment: @BhavikShah Conitnued, Then, with that remainder value, I get the letter (value) of the index(remainder) in the ArrayList. That then, is the Plaintext value. Then it moves on to the next Letter in the ciphertext/key pair.   Somewhat understand? Sorry for the poor explanation if not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you look into

[StringBuilder#append()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28char%29)

Adding characters to String Object is not recommended since **[String is immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798403/string-is-immutable-what-exactly-is-the-meaning)** which will create a new object everytime (if the string you are creating is not already in **[String pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801343/what-is-string-pool-in-java)**)

**Update :**

If you are looking for performance too, (and by any change there are a lot of string comparisons in your program) here is my suggestion:

use `strRef1 == strRef2` instead of `strRef1.equals(strRef2)`

Since, `String` is immutable and the concept of `String` pool the references of Strings will always be equal so if

`strRef1.equals(strRef2)` returns `true` `strRef1 == strRef2` should always return true.

**Exception :** this would not work if you create a new string explicitly like

`strRef2 = new String();`

Comment: Completely forgot about that! Thanks for the quick and kind reminder! :)

Comment: @BhavikShah Well good catch about pools, but I think String pools (using with 'String#intern()') is a little bit hard for beginners ;-)

Comment: @MenoHochschild : agreed

Answer (score 5):

Since String is final (designed as immutable) you need to create every time new Strings. For repeated times I recommend to use `StringBuilder` and then (after all char additions) convert it to String via `toString()`-method.

Comment: Gaah! How didn't I think of that! Thanks for the quick reminder! Accepting answer as soon as I am permitted to!

Comment: Please also keep in mind that `StringBuilder#append()` is much more efficient than using the + operator for string-concatenation.

Comment: I realize that. As embarrassing as this may sound, I actually am using a StringBuilder in the current program I am writing....maybe its time I get some sleep haha

Comment: Strings being `final` has nothing to do with that. It's because they are *immutable* that you want a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel thanks for the hint, implicitly I have meant this, but the term "immutable" is much more precise.

Answer (score 4):

You could try

```
string += newChar;
```

where `string` is the initial `String` object and `newChar` is the string or character you want to append to the original string.

NOTE: This is not as efficient as using `StringBuilder.append(...)`. If efficiency matters to you, you're better off with the other method. This, however, would suffice for very basic use cases.

Answer (score 4):

Since strings are immutable, use StringBuilder so that you don't create a new String every time you want your String to include an additional letter

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this from earlier answers, but thanks for the response regardless!