# String trim() method

Tags: java, string, trim

In Java I have written below code for string trim() method.

```
           if(" String ".trim() == "String")
               System.out.println("Equal");
           else
               System.out.println("Not Equal");
```

It gives output `Not Equal`s which I understood because `" String ".trim()` had returned  new `String` object  reference .

But when I trim and compare without white spaces it gives output `Equals`.

```
            if("String".trim() == "String")
               System.out.println("Equal");
           else
              System.out.println("Not Equal");
```

If String is not having white spaces what `trim()`  method returns?
I know `equals()` I can use but in my exam I got this question.

Comment: This is a result of Java's string pooling. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801343/what-is-string-pool-in-java

Comment: trim() method returns this, if there are no whitespaces

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does swift have a trim method on String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797739/does-swift-have-a-trim-method-on-string)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you look at the API? This is clearly stated in documentation of `trim()` method:

> **Returns:** A copy of this string with leading and trailing white space
>   removed, **or this string** if it has no leading or trailing white space.

You could have also gone through the source code. The `trim()` method returns `this`, if there are no whitespaces removed at either ends:

```
public String trim() {
    int len = value.length;
    int st = 0;
    char[] val = value;    /* avoid getfield opcode */

    while ((st < len) && (val[st] <= ' ')) {
        st++;
    }
    while ((st < len) && (val[len - 1] <= ' ')) {
        len--;
    }
    return ((st > 0) || (len < value.length)) ? substring(st, len) : this;
}
```

So, if both `st > 0` and `len < value.length` are false, which would be case for strings that don't have whitespaces at either ends, it returns `this`.

Now, why `"String" == "String"` is `true` is by the virtue of String interning. You can get lot more information about this through google.

Comment: Alternatively, the API (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html) already states: "Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted." So if there is no whitespace to omit, nothing is changed.

Comment: @SirRichie However the API doesn't make it clear whether a new copy is created or not for no whitespaces at the ends.

Comment: @SirRichie Oh! Actually the API makes it clear. Sorry for the misleading comment. I'll add the statement from API to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

If the [`trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) method would do nothing (because the string is already trimmed), the same string object (ie `this`) is returned.

[String interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) means that the string constant "String" is the exact same object used throughout the code wherever "String" is used.

These two facts together is why `==` is true for the comparison of `"String".trim() == "String"`.

Answer (score 0):

The `==` operator checks if it is the same object. 
To compare equality of the object, use `.equals()` method.
In your second case, the String which doesnt have whitespaces will no do anything to the Object. Hence it is equal, since the object is the same.