# How to trim start and end of string in Swift?

Tags: regex, string, swift

I'd like to trim `/` from the beginning and end of a string in Swift. Is there anything built or for this or what's a good way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does swift has trim method on String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797739/does-swift-has-trim-method-on-string)

Comment: Use the link provided by @AndréFratelli...but, here's a regex that would match what you want: [`/^\/+|\/+$/g`](https://regex101.com/r/wW2iP4/1)

Comment: Can you able to share your String code function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` in such cases, with a custom character set (here just "/"):

```
let original = "/word/"
let result = original.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "/"))
```

Result: "word"