# removing white spaces at beginning and end of string

Tags: ios, string, swift, whitespace, trim

I've got a problem with removing whitespaces at the beginning and end of string. For e.g. I've got a string like:

`\r\n\t- Someone will come here?\n- I don't know for sure...\r\n\r\n`

And I need to remove whitespaces **only** at the end and beginning (string should be look like:

`- Someone will come here?\n- I don't know for sure...`

Also there could be a lot of variants of string end: "\r\n\r\n", "\r\n", "\n\r\n" and so on...

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does swift has trim method on String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797739/does-swift-has-trim-method-on-string)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your string contains not only whitespace but also new line characters.

Use `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` with `whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet`.

```
let string = "\r\n\t- Someone will come here?\n- I don't know for sure...\r\n\r\n"
let trimmedString = string.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
```

In Swift 3 it's more *cleaned up*:

```
let trimmedString = string.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
```

Comment: well, this one is works with example so far, will try with other data. thank you

Comment: Thanks ! So easy! :)

Answer (score 6):

String trimming first and last whitespaces and newlines in **Swift 4+**

```
"  2 space  ".trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
```

result:
"2 space"

Answer (score 3):

```
//here i have used regular expression and replaced white spaces at the start and end
      let stringPassing : NSString? = "hdfjkhsdj hfjksdhf sdf "
      do {
        print("old->\(stringPassing)")
        let pattern : String = "(^\\s+)|(\\s+)$"
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern , options: [])
        let newMatched = regex.matchesInString(stringPassing! as String, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0,stringPassing!.length))
        if(newMatched.count > 0){

          let modifiedString = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(stringPassing! as String, options: [] , range: NSMakeRange(0,stringPassing!.length), withTemplate: "")
              print("new->\(modifiedString)")
        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this extension and just call "yourString".trim()

```
extension String
{
    func trim() -> String
    {
        return self.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to remove Whitespace from the start of the string Try this Code.**

```
func removeSpace()->String{
    let txt = myString
    var count:Int! = 0
    for i in txt{
        if i  == " "{
            count += 1
        }else{
            if count != 0{
                return String(txt.dropFirst(count))
            }else{
                return txt
            }
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

**Remove all whiteSpaces from the start of string**

```
func removeWhiteSpaces(str:String) -> String{
    var newStr = str
    for i in 0..<str.count{
        let index = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: i)
        print(str[index])
        if str[index] != " "{
            return newStr
        }
        else{
            newStr.remove(at: newStr.startIndex)
        }
    }
    return newStr
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In this code to restrict Textfield beginning white space

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if (textField.text?.count)! == 0 && string == " " {
            return false
        }
        else{
            return true
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

**In Swift 4**
Use it on any *String* type variable.

```
extension String {
    func trimWhiteSpaces() -> String {
        let whiteSpaceSet = NSCharacterSet.whitespaces
        return self.trimmingCharacters(in: whiteSpaceSet)
    }
}
```

And Call it like this

```
yourString.trimWhiteSpaces()
```

Answer (score -2):

You could first remove from the beginning and then from the end like so:

```
while true {
if sentence.characters.first == "\r\n" || sentence.characters.first == "\n" {
    sentence.removeAtIndex(sentence.startIndex)
} else {
    break
}
}

while true {
if sentence.characters.last == "\r\n" || sentence.characters.last == "\n" {
    sentence.removeAtIndex(sentence.endIndex.predecessor())
} else {
    break
}
}
```

Comment: I bet this is not a good idea to use while-true loop for such problem. By the way, string ending/beginning could be different. There are a lot of cases, and write all them down - also not good idea, as I think.

Comment: It breaks out of the loop once all of the spaces are removed (any combination of \n and \r\n. It will always trim the white spaces (and new lines) at the beginning and end ONLY. You should at least try it before down voting it.

Answer (score -2):

let string = "    exam ple  "

let trimmed = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "(^\s+)|(\s+)$", with: "", options: .regularExpression)

print(">" + trimmed3 + "<")

// prints >exam ple<