# How to check if a textFieldView is empty or has no spaces?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

```
textField.text.isEmpty
textField.text != ""
```

These two functions regard spaces as characters. However, I would like my to recognise when the text field has no spaces or is not empty.

Comment: You probably want to 'trim' whitespaces, just like in : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797739/does-swift-has-trim-method-on-string

Comment: Trim removes spaces and line-breaks from beginning and end of string.    That´s what you are looking for ? Take a look at: [Does swift has trim method on String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797739/does-swift-has-trim-method-on-string).

Comment: @Pieter21 That works fine, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just check if the trimmed string is empty

```
let isEmpty = str.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()).isEmpty
```

You can even put it in an `String` extension:

```
extension String {
    var isReallyEmpty: Bool {
        return self.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()).isEmpty
    }
}
```

It even works for a string like `var str = "         ​  "` (that has spaces, tabs and [zero-width spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space)).

Then simply check `textField.text?.isReallyEmpty ?? true`.

If you wanna go even further (I wouldn't) add it to an `UITextField` extension:

```
extension UITextField {
    var isReallyEmpty: Bool {
        return text?.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()).isEmpty ?? true
    }
}
```

Your code becomes `textField.isReallyEmpty`.

Answer (score 6):

In `Swift 4`,

```
extension String {
    var isReallyEmpty: Bool {
        return self.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this from @Pieter21 's link.
It works for as many blank spaces a user could enter.

```
let myString = TextField.text

let trimmedString = myString!.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(
    NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()
)

if trimmedString != "" {
    // Code if not empty
} else {
    // Code if empty
}
```