# Failing in comparing returned value with string

Tags: php, swift

I'm trying to return a value (string) from php to IOS application:

```
echo "1";
```

This is the swift code:

```
let returnedData = NSString(data: unwrappedData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String
print(returnedData)
if returnedData == "1" {
     ... something
}
```

The print function shows the correct value (that is, 1). 
But the check fails.

Comment: My guess: the returned string has a trailing newline ...

Comment: Why do you use NSString? `let unwrappedData = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)`

Comment: String(...) gives me Optional("1\n\n").

Comment: @MartinR Is there a way to check or remove the trailing newline?

Comment: @Fab: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26797739/1187415.

Comment: but use newlines charset or whitespaceAndNewLines `let newStr = str.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)`

Comment: @MartinR It works! Write it as answer, so I can vote it as best one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> String(...) gives me Optional("1\n\n")

That indicates that the output is followed by two newline characters, as in this
example:

```
let data = Data(bytes: [0x31, 0x0a, 0x0a])
if let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
    print(string) // 1
    print(string.debugDescription) // "1\n\n"
    print(string == "1") // false
}
```

`debugDescription` is a very useful method to detect “invisible” string
characters.

The solution is (compare [Does swift have a trim method on String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797739/does-swift-have-a-trim-method-on-string)):

```
let trimmed = string.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
print(trimmed == "1") // true
```