# If() inside WHILE-BufferedReader.readLine() does not work

Tags: java, android

UPDATE: 
Thank you all for your answers, especially pertaining to .equals().

The only detail is that the "msgCode = ..." and "msgValue = ..." statements are enough to return an empty stirngBuilder. I.e., I don't even have to declare the IF statement to make it stop working.

Any clues?

ORIGINAL:
Please let me know why `StringBuilder` returns nothing (perhaps doesn't even work) when I include the rest of the code (besides `stringBuilder.append(...)`) inside the `while()`.

When I include just `stringBuilder.append(...)`, then there is a return value.

```
while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
    stringBuilder.append(receiveString + "\n");

    // analyze the first 3 characters in the message
    String msgCode = receiveString.substring(0, 3);
    Number msgValue =  Integer.parseInt(receiveString.substring(4, receiveString.length()-4));

    // use IF-ELSE since SWITCH doesn't work with String
    if (msgCode=="ATT") {
        dataATT[2*dataATTcount+1] = msgValue; 
        dataATTcount++;
    } else {
        dataMED[2*dataMEDcount+1] = msgValue; 
        dataMEDcount++;                     
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: check the answer...http://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/2764279

Comment: There is no 'if inside BufferedReader.readLine()' here.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, especially pertaining to .equals(). 

The only detail is that the "msgCode = ..." and "msgValue = ..." statements are enough to return an empty stirngBuilder. I.e., I don't even have to declare the IF statement to make it stop working.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
msgCode.equals("ATT")
```

instead of

```
msgCode=="ATT"
```

with '==' you compare the references of the string and not the string itself.

Answer (score 0):

Never-ever use `==` for Java string comparison. Use `equals()`.

P.S. Okay, there might be some cases where `==` would be suitable. But for the vast majority of situations, `equals()` is the way to go.

Comment: what are those cases?

Comment: @blackbelt `"hell" + "o" == "he" + "llo"` -- If you want to know more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801343/what-is-string-pool-in-java But it's a very rare case.