# Create New Strings in normal memory and in string pool

Tags: java, string, string-pool

If for example:

```
String str1 = “abc”;
String str2 = new String(“def”);
```

Then,

**Case 1**: `String str3 = str1.concat(str2)` will go in the heap or pool?

**Case 2**: `String str4 = str2.concat(“HI”)` will go in the heap or pool?

Comment: all strings go in the pool. `New String` will create a new string even a same string is existed in the pool

Comment: String s = "abc"; // creates one String object and one
// reference variable
In this simple case, "abc" will go in the pool and s will refer to it.
String s = new String("abc"); // creates two objects,
// and one reference variable
In this case, because we used the new keyword, Java will create a new String object
in normal (nonpool) memory, and s will refer to it. In addition, the literal "abc" will
be placed in the pool.

Comment: looks like dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/java-string-pool and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801343/what-is-string-pool-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first syntax`(String str1 = "abc";)`, just one String object is created and one reference variable pointing to it. The object is created in the String constant pool maintained by JVM.
In the second case `String str2 = new String("def");`, two String objects are created. Since new is called, one String object is created in the normal memory. Also, the string constant "newstring" will be placed in the String constant pool.

So when we don't have New Keyword, we just have one String object is created in the String constant pool.

Answer (score 0):

In java, whichever String u create using new keyword will be created in heap memory. If you create any String without using new, it will created in String pool and it will be called as String Constant. There will be only one copy of String constant pool value which means duplicates wont be there in String pool.