# Java String if+ contains+ loop

Tags: java, string, contains

Pseudocode:

```
In Loop for n-iterations {
    // I am doing a check below
    if (params.contains("test") {

    }
}
```

Will the string `test` be created as object `n` times?

Comment: No.  There will be one string instance created for `"test"`.  Java is actually fairly aggressive about caching and reusing `String` instances.  For further discussion, see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801343/what-is-string-pool-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.. `"test"` is a String *literal* , so it goes into the *String constants pool* and will be *reused* for all future accesses of "test". if you do `new String("test")` (bad way of creating String) ,then several instances of the String "test" will be created - one for each *iteration*

Comment: Also worth noting that any other methods that output a `String` object representing "test" are almost certain to create other instances.

Comment: @JRichardSnape - That depends.. For example if you call `trim()` on `"test"`, then the same `"test"` instance will be returned.

Comment: absolutely - hence the "almost" certain. To be honest, it's deviating from the exact question somewhat.  It can be the source of nasty "gotchas" for some, hence my comment, but you've answered the question.

Answer (score 3):

No. `"test"` is a unique object, that is stored in the String pool. It's thus even the same object as any other `"test"` literal you might have elsewhere in the application.