# using an if statement with an && in it not working correctly

Tags: java, if-statement

Original code:

```
if (!externals.containsKey(query.getName())) {
```

I need to check also if query.getName() != "manualPrice" so my code becomes:

```
if ((!externals.containsKey(query.getName())) && (query.getName() != "manualPrice")) {
```

this isn't giving me the desired result. I'm not getting errors but the page isnt loading.

However annoyingly enough this code does work (it just doesnt feel as neat):

```
if (!externals.containsKey(query.getName())) {
  if (query.getName() != "manualPrice") {
```

is there something really obvious I'm missing out. Im not normally at Java developer but do know C# which is pretty similar from what I've seen. Im hoping its just something silly I've missed.

cheers

UPDATE *****

ok so people have pointed out that rather than == i should be using .equals

which I have done. my new code is:

```
if ((!externals.containsKey(query.getName())) && (!query.getName().equals("manualPrice"))) {
```

which still gives the same error as it did with the ==

I'm begrudgingly using the nested if method for now but its just got me baffled as to what could possibly be wrong with it. It compiles fine!

Comment: Use `query.getName().equals("manualPrice")`

Comment: @LydiaRalph I was thinking that too but it doens't explain why the last nested if works, whereas the on-liner doens't .. ?

Comment: Because of De-Morgan's laws.

Comment: @MarounMaroun er ... no. Sorry. That's a cryptic comment and at first glance, and second glance, seems to be incorrect.

Comment: I'm very cryptic now.

Comment: In both cases, try doing `System.out.printf("%d, %d\n", System.identityHashCode("manualPrice"), System.identityHashCode(query.getName()));`. I bet it's just a coincidence it works in one case and not the other.

Comment: @MarounMaroun lol.. yes! I'd like to understand the answer to this question too, but so far as I can see adding .equals instead of != won't explain why the second nested arrangement of ifs works when the one-liner doesn't. The logic is the same, you're just replacing the && with a nested if.

Comment: Agreed with @David. You might just be lucky in your second cases and both String happen to end up in the StringPool and have the same pointer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801343/what-is-string-pool-in-java. But really, here you are relying on some compiler optimization. In any cases you should never use == to compare String.

Comment: @user280805 you're probably reaching the code slightly differently, or some optimization is getting triggered. What if you made `"manualPrice"` a `private static final` variable?

Comment: hey guys. cheers for the correction on the .equals function. I've changed my code to use it

if ((!externals.containsKey(query.getName())) && (!query.getName().equals("manualPrice"))) {

but im still getting the same error

Comment: Please post a complete and reproducible example.