# Illogical null pointer exception

Tags: java, rest, nullpointerexception, resteasy

I'm doing a Rest integration project, and I'm trying a PUT api request for an API I'm implementing. This is part of the code that is on the start of the PUT operation implementation.

```
String name = vivienda.getName();
Vivienda oldVivienda = repository.getViviendas(name);
if (oldVivienda == null) {
    throw new NotFoundException("No se ha encontrado ninguna vivienda con el nombre="+ vivienda.getName());         
}
```

Thing is, when I do the request, it returns me the `NotFoundException` declared there, so it didn't work.

Playing with the code I localised that the error was that, certainly, the object `oldVivienda` was `null`, as if I tried to do something with its `getName`, it would throw `NullPointerException`.

But here's where I start not understanding anything. I changed the code to try and find where the error was, putting the name string directly like this:

```
Vivienda oldVivienda = repository.getViviendas("vivienda1");
if (oldVivienda == null) {
    throw new NotFoundException("No se ha encontrado ninguna vivienda con el nombre="+ vivienda.getName());         
}
```

This works perfectly. This would lead to thinking that the problem is with the parameter object `vivienda`, that it's or its name is empty or isn't "vivienda1". But, remember the exception? In the exception I use `vivienda.getName()`, and when I see the error thrown in the response, it actually says "vivienda1". So I sent fine the object, and when you do `vivienda.getName()` it returns "vivienda1". And when you put the string "vivienda1" in the `repository.getViviendas("vivienda1")`, it works perfectly.

So, where is the problem? Is there any problem with types? But `getName` is a simple get method that returns a String. And I've checked several times if there was a space somewhere or something. The error is in those 2 first lines of code, but I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: you need to debug using some breakpoints.... its look like this: ***vivienda.getName();*** is returning null

Comment: What is inside of your `repository` class? This behaviour could be explained if you're comparing strings with `==` operator inside of `repository`.

Comment: "_But, remember the exception?_" Well, no since you didn't provide it. ;)Are you sure there is no space or anything ? Please provide a [mcve] for this exception. Use `vivienda.getName().trim()` just in case.

Comment: The exception I'm talking about is in both pieces of code I provided, it's a simple throw new 404. And yup, that's right, the problem was in using == instead of equals, totally forgot about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this code works

```
repository.getViviendas("vivienda1");
```

while the following doesn't

```
repository.getViviendas(name); // name is "vivienda1"
```

it could mean that `String` comparison is done incorrectly inside of `repository`.

If you're declaring two Strings as literals then comparison using `==` operator will be successful since they'll be stored in a String pool. But if the value of one of those strings comes in dynamically (like from your RESTful API client) then it will not work.

Please read [What is String pool in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801343/what-is-string-pool-in-java) for more details on String pool in Java.

The correct way to compare Strings in Java is `.equals()` method:

```
someString.equals(otherString);
```