# How String Pool Internal code as StringConstantPool is deprecated?

Tags: java, string, string-pool

Could you Please let m me know the exact class which is behind **Stringpool** implementation as I wanted to know how it has implemented the **FlyWeightDesign Pattern**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801343/what-is-string-pool-in-java

Comment: Thanks Hash Jang . But Actually wanted to know the internal implementation of pool As I entioned above How it has implemented FlyweihtDesignPattern

Answer (score 0):

String pool is not implemented in Java source. You will not find the source code in Java. Check java.lang.String.intern() native method. I think most of the JVM implementations have String pool implemented in C++. I also remember reading somewhere that it can be done in other ways too.