# Number of String objects created when String is passed as method parameter in Java

Tags: java, string

if I call any method and i passes string as parameter.
for example,

```
****some code***
somemethod("rohit");

*****some code ****

somemethod(String name){ 

  ***some code***
}
```

Now in this case how many string object will be created?
means, hardcoded "rohit" also created as an object and argument name also creates one more object.

Comment: Method parameters are just new variables pointing to the same object/instance. Using string literals (quotation marks) to create strings will use string interning. That means that it comes out of an internal cache. So writing `"huhu"` 100 times in your code only leads to one string `"huhu"` being created and the rest comes out of the cache, pointing to the same object.

Comment: Cache means String pool right? @Zabuza

Comment: Yes. Just google "String interning", its a common technique. Wikipedia has a nice explanation.

Answer (score 2):

When you write `rohit`, it will create a new String object. But when you pass it to a method argument, another variable (here `name`) will just point to that previously created object. It won't create a new object. So in total, only one String object will be created in your case. Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12429953/5353128

Comment: somemethod("rohit"); such method i called many times in my java application. is this reduce performance of application?

Comment: If it's "rohit" every time, then no new object will be created because of String pool in Java. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801343/what-is-string-pool-in-java If name changes every time, create a variable with a name and then pass variable to all the methods instead of hard coding the values

Comment: @rohit_mhetre you can accept the answer if this is what you were looking for!

Answer (score -1):

Strings can be created as a reference object or at String pool. If We declare it as Objects it will consider about the value and only one object will created.Here when you code it as **rohit** it will create new object. But if you pass it as parameter reference it won't create any new objects

Comment: It's exactly the reverse of what you're saying. Using a literal string like "rohit" here only ever creates one object because it is looked up through the pool.